# How can I fix it? : Could not find artifact org.ethereum:rocksdbjni:pom:5.9.2 in ethereum (https://dl.bintray.com/ethereum/maven/)

Tags: java, ethereum, blockchain

In my Java SDK project needs to interact with the blockchain. My environment is Windows, IDEA, JDK17. There is such a warehouse reference in my pom.xml file.

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ethereum</id>
        <name>ethereum</name>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/ethereum/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But this error occurred. I cannot access this URL.

> Could not find artifact org.ethereum:rocksdbjni:pom:5.9.2 in ethereum
> (https://dl.bintray.com/ethereum/maven/)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: url request is forbidden , check the network is accessible

Comment: if it internal  , pls add deploy pom ```org.ethereum:rocksdbjni```  in repository

Comment: [the bintray repo was shut down in 2021](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-maven-plugin/issues/65)

Comment: @Peng The request is not forbidden. Given Bintray was shut down, all requests result in a 404 (the host still exists, but no longer contains any artifacts).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks for additional remarks

Answer (score 0):

The Maven repository you're referencing was hosted on Bintray, but Bintray was [shut down in 2021](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/), and all requests to the host `dl.bintray.com` now result in a HTTP 404 not found error.

You'll need to find a replacement repository, or use the normal `rocksdbjni` dependency. Though to be clear, I don't know if that will work as I guess there was a special reason the Ethereum project released a separate artifact.

In any case, the normal RocksDB dependency is on Maven Central:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

(FYI, this is a version from 2018, the latest version at this time is 8.6.7 from 8 November 2023.)